# Convert paged columns to rows with a regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

So first a sample of the actual data mangled (data is originally a mix of text and numbers, there's no significance to any of the data at this point and some of the patterns are just because I replaced most of the characters with 0s, 1s and Zs because the random number generator in my brain is broken):

```
011.0ZN1ZZ                 001.F5ZS1Z                 001.ZO5ZY0    
014.5ZZZ1Z                 001.1SZZOZ                 001.ZLMZY0    
016.01NM1SU54              001.EX0Z1Z                 001.LIZZOZ    
018.01NM1SS41              001.F83Z1Z                 001.0011M1SU54
014.ZZ1YZZ                 001.ZZZ1IZ                 001.0011M1SS41
013.2EBSIZ                 001.ZZZ11Z                 001.0011SE4

01N.ZINSIZ                 001.ZZZZ1Z                 P01.ZZZZ1Z
01N.01NSE4                 001.LSZZHG                 N01.ZZZZ1Z    
001.01ON5O                 001.5Z21OL                 F01.ZZZZ1Z    
001.NE5ZO1                 001.ZOM05O                 D01.ZZZZ1Z    
001.ZO5ZOZ                 001.01NO1G                 Z01.ZZZZ1Z    
001.ZO5ZOZ                 001.01NO1G                 Z01.ZZZZ1Z  

001.011ZOZ                 001.01NZ0Y
```

Some additional comments.. I can clean up whitespace and deal with record length with no issues, so I'd like to simplify the question to this, I'm just including the above in case there's a solution to the simplified version that can't be easily extended to a more complex version.

```
1 7 13
2 8 14
3 9 15
4 10 16
5 11 17
6 12 18

19 25
20 26
21 27
22 28
23 29
24
```

So there will be a variable number of pages, but the same number of columns and rows on each page (although, in case it matters significantly, it's actually 12x3 instead of 6x3 but I wanted to keep it simple if possible), although the last page may be some empty rows/columns.

I'm using notepad++ but I have access to various gnutilities so if there's a solution that's way, way better than a regular expression I don't mind, although since I'll be using this a lot and use notepad++ a lot I'd appreciate a regex solution if it isn't too insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got Git installed on your Windows machine, you may use Perl bundled with it from Git bash. Provided your input file is named `data`, try the following command (**caution**: it will orverwrite the input file):

```
echo >>data ; \
perl -i -lane'
    $i=0;
    push @{$c[$i++]}, $_ foreach @F; 
    if (/^\s*$/) {
        push @l, @{$_} foreach @c;
        print "@l\015";
        @l=@c=();
    }' data
```

The Perl command treats each line of input as space delimited fields and accumulates the fields in the `@c` matrix. When encounters an empty line (`if (/^\s*$/) ...`), it prints the matrix columns concatenated in a list.

The input file is changed in-place. A backup copy `data.bak` is created.

The input file may not end with an empty line so I add one with `echo >>data`. This makes the Perl script shorter and easier.

Another trick is the trailing `\015` in `print "@l\015";`. This allows us to get Windows CRLF line endings in Unix-flavoured Git bash environment.

A demo can be found here: https://ideone.com/vnYoOd. But since Ideone forbids file read/write, the original command has been modified to make the code run there.

Comment: Thanks.. This doesn't do exactly what I want as I pictured it, but it meets the requirements I specified and I understand it well enough to tweak it. Once I have time to do so I'll add another comment here with the code I actually used. The only real correction I'd make here is:
print "@l\012\015"; although honestly from what I can tell you can just do \r\n and it produces the same result, but I assume 012 015 is probably better in case an interpreter treats \r and \n differently (if that's not standard) I'd still love a regex solution but unless/til I get one I've marked this as the solution